# better PEMDAS Calculator function?

Tags: javascript

So I was trying to make a calculator that uses a PEMDAS Sequnce;
PEMDAS - (Parenthesis, Exponents, Multiplication, Division, Addition, Subtraction)

tho Im only using the MDAS here.

I had this eval function to return the result.
But this code seems slow tbh especially when the user inputs multiple numbers.
And it gets stuck.

```
function eval(inputval) {

    // Takes the input as an array - 
    // example inputVal = 1 + 2 turns into [1,+,2] = value
    let value = inputval.split(" "); 

    // for solving and replacing the elements of the array.
    let result = 0; 
    let operators = ["x","/","+","-"], n = 0;

    // PEMDAS Sequence.
    while (value.length != 1) {
        for (i of value) {

            if ( (operators[n] == i) && (operators[n] == "x") ) {
                result = Number(value[value.indexOf(i) - 1]) * Number(value[value.indexOf(i) + 1]);
                value.splice(value.indexOf(i) - 1, 3, result);
                result = 0;

            }

            else if ( (operators[n] == i) && (operators[n] == "/") ) {
                result = Number(value[value.indexOf(i) - 1]) / Number(value[value.indexOf(i) + 1]);
                value.splice(value.indexOf(i) - 1, 3, result);
                result = 0;
            }

            else if ( (operators[n] == i) && (operators[n] == "+") ) {
                result = Number(value[value.indexOf(i) - 1]) + Number(value[value.indexOf(i) + 1]);
                value.splice(value.indexOf(i) - 1, 3, result);
                result = 0;
            }

            else if ( (operators[n] == i) && (operators[n] == "-") ) {
                result = Number(value[value.indexOf(i) - 1]) - Number(value[value.indexOf(i) + 1]);
                value.splice(value.indexOf(i) - 1, 3, result);
                result = 0;
            }

        }
        n += 1;
    }
    Calvalue.value = value[0];
}
```

Im just wondering how can I improve this code?
Srry Im still learning.